# Conditional Filegroup File script in Visual Studio 2010 database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2010 database project. Inside the project, I've added two Storage -> Filegroup File scripts: one for my primary data file (.mdf) and one for my log file (.ldf). This will be expanded in the future.

[image]

Right now, the `Build Action` is set to `Build` on both of these files.

The contents of each file is simple. The only reason I really created them was to have full control over their file names.

**Primary.sql:**

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
ADD FILE
    (
        NAME = [Primary],
        FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix).mdf'
    );
```

**Log.sql:**

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD LOG FILE
        (
            NAME = [Log],
            FILENAME = '$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Log.ldf'
        );
```

When I publish my data project to create a new database, behind the scenes, the following TSQL/SQLCMD is rendered. This is exactly what I want:

```
PRINT N'Creating $(DatabaseName)...'
GO
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ON 
    PRIMARY(NAME = [Primary], FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix).mdf')
    LOG ON (NAME = [Log], FILENAME = '$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Log.ldf') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO
```

However, when I publish changes to an existing database (say for example that I add a new table), the following TSQL/SQLCMD is rendered instead:

```
PRINT N'Creating [Primary]...';
GO
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD FILE (NAME = [Primary], FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix).mdf') TO FILEGROUP [PRIMARY];
GO
PRINT N'Creating [Log]...';
GO
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD LOG FILE (NAME = [Log], FILENAME = '$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Log.ldf');
```

This is not what I want since the .mdf files and .ldf files already exists. How can I modify my storage scripts so they place nice in both scenarios: creating a new database and updating an existing database??

Any ideas?

**Update 8/18**

I thought I could simply wrap the storage scripts in an IF/EXISTS type check. If the file already exists, don't do anything. That doesn't seem to work. It actually prevents the solution from building altogether:

So something like:

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM sys.master_files as mf WHERE DB_NAME(mf.[database_id]) = [$(DatabaseName)] AND name = '[Primary]'))
BEGIN
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD FILE
        (
            ...
        );
END
```

produces the following compiler error:

```
Error   200 SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context.
```

The way these scripts get handled behind the scenes (new database vs update) makes me think they can't be conditional.

Comment: Can you try putting a '\' in between? like: FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)\$(DefaultFilePrefix).ndf'

Comment: I think those are set correctly -> :setvar DefaultDataPath "E:\DATA\" - no slash needed.

Comment: you need to test if file already exists

Comment: One would think it would be that easy... See updated question in a bit.

Comment: can you not use action=build?

Comment: what would be the appropriate build action for this type of file? "build" was the default i think.

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 sql file, set build action as `PreDeploy`

[image]

And add your scripts in this file:

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM sys.master_files as mf WHERE DB_NAME(mf.[database_id]) = '[$(DatabaseName)]' AND name = '[Primary]'))
BEGIN

ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
ADD FILE
    (
        NAME = [Primary],
        FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix).mdf'
    );

ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD LOG FILE
        (
            NAME = [Log],
            FILENAME = '$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Log.ldf'
        );

END
```

This file will executes everytime on deploy and checks database exists.
But you will have only one PreDeploy file, so, any srcips should be added to this file, but it's not a big problem

Comment: The PreDeployment script might be the ticket, but when a new database is created, the database project automatically creates a data file and log file via CREATE DATABASE statement. This happens before the PreDeploy. Therefore, Primary will already exists and this code will not execute.

Comment: At the end of the day, I just want to customize the names of the data file and log file. I can't believe there's not a way to override this.

Comment: @JohnRussell I spent an evening trying to do this, Database project has many options connected to file groups but ALL of them don't work - neither I check option not uncheck - no difference. So, i created a pre-deploy file - it seems working, but I'll try case with database creation

Comment: @JohnRussell what I have: if you publish new DB with this file scripts - everything is OK later. The problem is when you have the file with the same name (NAME = [Primary]) but different filename (FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix).mdf). It always must have a file with this filename

Comment: @JohnRussell at the end, I am totally confused of its behavior, i can't understand, what and when it does - when add file, when - not. Terrible :)